# How to relate to information_schema

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, relational-theory, information-schema

Is it possible to create a foreign key that relates to `information_schema`?

For an application implementation, I would like to store extra column information in another table, but I want to ensure that it is not describing columns that do not exist.

Is it possible to have a foreign key that relates to information_schema?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a foreign key that relates to information_schema

No.

`information_schema` contains views. You can't have a foreign key to a view.

You can't set a foreign key to point at the underlying `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` table that defines columns, either, because foreign keys to system catalogs are not supported.